# Qualcomm Atheros AR8172 Driver fix? (lenovo g500s)

Tags: networking, lenovo, ethernet, atheros

Recently I took a **lenovo g500s** laptop. the product id is **LENOVO_MT_20245**. after the installation, it could not recognize LAN network adapter. After googling I found out that it has a `Qualcomm Atheros AR8172/8176/8178 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller`

Command `lspci -nn | grep 0200` says:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
```

Anybody know a way to fix this driver?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your ethernet card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0200

Comment: 01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED]

first enter `lspci -nn | grep 0200` 
and make sure that your drivers is "Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet[1969:10a0]"

The following fix is is only going to work for-

```
1969:1091 - AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
1969:1090 - AR8162 Fast Ethernet
1969:10A1 - QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
1969:10A0 - QCA8172 Fast Ethernet
```

adapters.  and please make sure that your kernel is 2.6.24 or above. It is technically possible for kernels < 2.6.24 but might take some work. (still worth giving a try!)
to check the kernel version type

```
uname -a
```

after that, If they are all neat and right.
download [compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/04/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2) file and extract it.
go to the extracted directory [ex-  `cd Downloads/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/`]
and type-

```
sudo ./scripts/driver-select alx

sudo make

sudo make install
```

reboot the system you are all done :)
apparently this type of ethernet adapters are available in lenovo g500s, lenovo g500 series, lenovo g400 series, asus 3rd gen laptops, (you better check before installing)

for more information go to [http://www.linuxfoundation.org](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx)

Thanks to Lusus Naturae. His forum showed me this way. so the rewards goes to him. [original link-]
http://meinewenigkeit.blogspot.com/2013/08/gentoo-and-atheros-qca8172-fast-ethernet.html

Answer (score 0):

Your device 1969:10a0 is covered by the driver *alx* by default in Ubuntu 13.04. I suggest you upgrade to 13.04.

Answer (score -1):

The compile errors are basically redefinitions of already defined functions.
For me, I was on Kernel 3.2.x and in the include/linux/compat-2.6.h file I just commented out everything after #include , because the compile errors were in 3.4, 3.7 and 3.8.
So basically I commented out all lines from include compat-3.4.h thru compat-3.9.h.
After that the compile and the install worked.

Hope that helps, Denis.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)